# Laravel Роут по Патерну

Tags: php, laravel, route

Есть ли возможность в Laravel зарегистрировать роут который будет выполняться только при определенном префиксе игнорируя uri?

то есть  допустим url после префикса может иметь n-ное количество вложений (слешей).

например"/get_com/любая_строка/возможная_строка/аможет_еще_одна_или_нет/..."

чтобы роут срабатывал при /get_com/ и любом содержимом после.

Comment: `Есть ли возможность...?` - есть.

Comment: Ну хотелось бы более развернутый ответ. возможность есть всегда. можно и костыль впихнуть 

`if(preg_match("/^(\/summ\/)(.*)/",request()->getRequestUri(),$m)){

    $m[2]=preg_replace("/\/$/","",$m[2]);

    $am2= array_map(function($key,$i){ return "{path_".

($i+1)."}";},explode("/",$m[2]),array_keys(explode("/",$m[2])));


    Route::get('/summ/'.join("/",$am2), function(){

        dd("dsfasdf");

    });

}`
или в провайдере все сделать. я просто ищу самый оптимальный и правильный вариант

Comment: `Route::get('get_com/{params?}', 'Controller@method')->where('params', '(.*)');` Что-то в этом роде можно, `explode('/', $params)` - массив всех параметров

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'get_com'], function() {
    Route::fallback(function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        dd($request->url());
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо =) хороший вариант. правда не воспользовался.
моя реализация отдает файл. поэтому сделал обработку реquest url до роутов.
и сам отдал файл и закрыл приложение.